# Swift static members in extensions and a declaration cannot be both 'final' and 'dynamic'

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors

I'm experiencing a strange bug, and even though there are answered questions about it, none really explains what's going on.

If I define the following class in Swift 3.0, the compiler creates a dynamic getter for pi for Objective-C:

```
@objc class Thing : NSObject {

    public static let pi = NSNumber(value:3.1415926)
}
```

However, if I move the declaration into an extension, all hell breaks loose:

```
@objc class Thing : NSObject {


}

extension Thing{
    public static let pi = NSNumber(value:3.1415926)

}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: a declaration cannot be both 'final' and 'dynamic'
```

Why is it any different declaring it in an extension or in the body of the class?

Who is final??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A declaration cannot be both 'final' and 'dynamic' error in Swift 1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814706/a-declaration-cannot-be-both-final-and-dynamic-error-in-swift-1-2)